# Transferring a textfield value from a source page to several target pages : Object type casting error

Tags: asp.net, object, webforms, transfer

```
// SourcePage.aspx 
public partial class SourcePage: System.Web.UI.Page 
{ 
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        //...... 
        //...... 

            while (rdr.Read()) 
            { 
                txtName.Text = rdr["Name"].ToString(); 
            } 
            rdr.Close(); 
    } 

    public string GetName 
    { 
        get { return txtName.Text; } 
    } 

    protected void btnServer.Transfer_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
       Server.Transfer("TargetPage1.aspx"); 
       Server.Transfer("TargetPage2.aspx"); 
    } 
} 

//TargetPage1.aspx   
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
            SourcePage SP; 
            SP = (SourcePage)Context.Handler; // I get runtime error here: unable to cast object of type 'ASP.TargetPage_aspx' to type 'SourcePage' 
            txtTPName.Text = p.GetName; 
}
```

Where I am wrong? Can't really figure it out. I need to transfer the values from the sourcepage to other target pages, and I don't want to use several queries. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Page.PreviousPage`

Using this property you'd be able to access all original page controls.

```
TextBox txtName = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("txtName");
txtTPName.Text = txtName.Text;
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example for Page.PreviousPage? I mean exact (what is where?); because I have tried with this and had problems too

Comment: @M Rokon Jaman: Check the msdn reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx

Comment: @M Rokon Jaman: session is a valid mechanism to share information across pages so if worked well for you then this is resolved :)

Comment: @MRokonJaman: I rolled back your edit on this answer. It changed it completely and should have been a new answer (which you already posted anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I solved the issue using session variables instead, here is how..

Source page : codebehind: after the connection follow..

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();          
sda.SelectCommand = cmd;         
sda.Fill(dt);          
foreach (DataRow Row in dt.Rows)         
{             
txtSource.Text = Row["Name"].ToString();      
    }  
        Session.Add("sp", dt);
```

Then in the Target page :

```
    DataTable dt = Session["sp"] as DataTable;    
 foreach (DataRow Row in dt.Rows)    
 {      
   txtTarget.Text = Row["Name"].ToString();  
   }
```

Now I can initialize this datatable 
   in any other pages and can have required data from there.